# Grouping of output plots from function

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, seaborn

Here is something I have been struggling with today. It's a question of how to present data in such a way as to avoid having to scroll downa notebook for ages and loosing the ability to compare graphs.

Suppose I have this dataframe:

```
id type zone    d
0    1    a   a1   23
1    1    a   b1   45
2    1    a   c1   23
3    2    a   c1   56
4    2    b   a1    7
5    2    b   b1    5
6    3    b   a1    2
7    3    b   a1    9
8    3    b   b1   43
9    4    c   c1   21
10   4    c   c1   67
11   5    c   b1   34
12   5    c   a1   21
13   1    a   a1    3
14   1    a   b1    4
15   1    a   c1   12
16   2    a   c1   10
17   2    b   a1   33
18   2    b   b1   22
19   3    b   a1  334
20   3    b   a1   22
21   3    b   b1   11
22   4    c   c1   55
23   4    c   c1   88
24   5    c   b1   22
25   5    c   a1    9
```

and the following function

```
def my_function(df,zone):
    df_new = df[df['zone']=="{}".format(zone)]
    df_new.hist()
    plt.suptitle("distances for zone {}".format(zone))
```

I generate one graph per zone doing the following

```
zoneList = list(set(df['zone'].unique()))

for zone in zoneList:
    my_function(df,zone)
```

Now this returns a sequence of barplots, one on top of the other. This is not very convenient. What I would like is for these plots to be in a grid, say 2 plots by row.

I tried this:

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, 2)
for zone in zoneList:
    axs = my_function(df,zone)
```

but it returns the grid I want and then the same result that I previously got.

How can I solve this?

Comment: This existing code works without issue to create 3 plots (zone 1 - 3), each with 2 subplots (id and d) in `pandas 1.3.0` and `matplotlib 3.4.2`. This can all be done in a single line with `ax = df.pivot(columns='zone', values=['id', 'd']).hist(figsize=(7, 10))`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have created a grid that you want, but you have not used it anywhere.

`pandas.DataFrame.hist()` has an argument `ax` as:

> **ax : Matplotlib axes object, default None**
>
> The axes to plot the histogram on.

This code:

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, 2)
```

returns a Matplotlib figure `fig` and `numpy.array` of Matplotlib axes objects `axs` (1-dimensional if either rows or columns is 1, 2-dimensional otherwise).

So, you need to:

1. loop over the flattened version of `axs`
2. pass respective `ax` object to `df_new.hist()` method

Like such:

```
def my_function(df,zone,ax):
    df_new = df[df['zone']=="{}".format(zone)]
    df_new.hist(ax = ax)
    # set title just for this subplot
    ax.set_title("distances for zone {}".format(zone), loc = 'center')

fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, 2)
for zone, ax in zip(zoneList, axs.flatten()):
    my_function(df,zone,ax)
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with a loop:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 2)

for zone in df['zone'].unique():
    ax[0].hist(df[df['zone'] == zone]['d'], label = zone, bins = np.arange(df['d'].min(), df['d'].max() + 10, 10))
    ax[1].hist(df[df['zone'] == zone]['id'], label = zone, bins = np.arange(df['id'].min(), df['id'].max() + 0.5, 0.5))

ax[0].set_title('d')
ax[1].set_title('id')
ax[1].legend(frameon = True)

plt.show()
```

[image]

---

Or with [`seaborn.histplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.histplot.html):

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 2)

sns.histplot(ax = ax[0], data = df, x = 'd', hue = 'zone', binwidth = 10)
sns.histplot(ax = ax[1], data = df, x = 'id', hue = 'zone', binwidth = 0.5)

plt.show()
```

[image]